# PostgreSQL only clear user password

Tags: postgresql

I am having a big problem, quite difficult to find/search.
I have a server in Ubuntu, where inside that server I have installed:

- GITLAB (have all proyect)
- POSTGRESSQL (Independent gitlab database is used for a personal project)
- TOMCAT with APP WEB (Springboot, this use postgres)

This server is still for testing, it is used for specific specific things (I mean, its use and access is limited and controlled)

I am having various problems:

1. This server is still for testing, it is used for specific specific things (I mean, its use and access is limited and controlled)
2. Very frequently, almost every day, the user postgres from the postgresql server "erases" the password. Without anyone doing it manually, "it happens exponentially". I notice why the application stops responding, and then I access postgresql and note that the postgres user has no password.

I looked for many places, and I can't find anything. I really don't know where else to look. If someone passed it to you or has information about it, I would be grateful if you could provide it to me.

------More information added----------

I was looking at the postgres logs, before I have no authentication and I see this.

[image: Logpostgres]

There are times when no one could have been using the springboot server,
--2020-01-17 00:30:21.286
And also the two log that show before that moment. Could it be something that is deleting my password?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you are able to login without a password or that the postgres user literally has no password.  How are you determining that the user does not have a password?

Comment: @Jeremy User has password, but at some point the password is deleted, and I can enter with the user without password. And nobody has manually deleted it. Also, I can see it in pgadmin, when I log in with another user with the same privileges as "postgres", I notice that he doesn't have a password.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand and won't get you help any faster. It's also somewhat impolite to SHOUT AT US when you're asking us for free help. There is also insufficient detail in your post. Read it from our point of view, considering we know absolutely nothing about what you're doing other than what you've provided. *I have this server that I use for testing. Access is controlled and limited. I won't tell you specifics about what I'm doing with it, but it sporadically has a problem.* isn't enough information.

Comment: I edited the title to remove them when I posted that comment, which you can see by following the [history] link (located to the right of your avatar, almost centered under your question). I didn't say *scream* anywhere, and in the modern world every site knows that TEXT WRITTEN IN ALL CAPS is considered to be shouting, and SO is in the modern world. When an experienced user tries to help you by proving information about this site, they're trying to help improve your experiences here, as I did by both editing your post and leaving the comment to inform you.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not randomly delete its own passwords, and I really doubt Tomcat or Gitlab do either.  Indeed they shouldn't even have access to the server as the 'postgres' user or any other superuser, and so shouldn't be able to even if they wanted.

It seems like that there is an intruder in your system.  After gaining access they create their own user with their own password.  Then disabling your normal superuser from logging on is a common way to try to prevent you from regaining control and kicking them out.  Do any users exist that you do not recognize?

The bit of the log file you posted clearly shows someone trying to guess your password, starting at 2:58.  You aren't logging IP addresses (%h) so it doesn't show where they are coming from.  It doesn't show that they succeed, but unless you have log_connections = on, it wouldn't show successes.

Comment: Users who enter the server, that I know not. I think the same, because there is another user created that works perfectly. But it makes me suspect gitlab since it also uses postgressql.I add extra information in my comment of a Log. Because it is also a strange behavior.Thank you very much for your prompt comment. I am quite new to this subject, I usually dedicate myself to other things.